# Change year of citation

Tags: biblatex

Here is what I have on my latex file:

```
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=alphabetic, bibstyle=ieee-alphabetic, sortcites=true,
  maxbibnames   = 99, maxalphanames = 8, maxcitenames  = 6, 
  minalphanames = 6, minnames = 4,
]{biblatex}
```

Here is what I have in my .bib file:

```
@article {ipv10,
 AUTHOR = {Ioana, Adrian and Popa, Sorin and Vaes, Stefaan},
  TITLE = {A class of superrigid group von {N}eumann algebras},
JOURNAL = {Annals of Mathematics}, 
 VOLUME = {178},
   YEAR = {2013},
 NUMBER = {1},
  PAGES = {231--286}, }
```

When I cite it on the `.tex` file, I get [IPV13]. However, I would like [IPV10] to appear. Is that possible? If so, what are the commands to get it?

Comment: Why do you want `[IPV10]`? It would be very unusual, because when the year is **2013** usually an alphabetic style should not show `10` (but **13**) after the author initials. So IMHO either it should be `[IPV13]` or the `year` is wrong. However, `biblatex` allows to force a label using the `shorthand` field. So adding `shorthand=IPV10` should do it. “should” because I currently cannot test, because you've not shown a [minimal working example with bibliography](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407/277964).

Comment: The reason why I want IPV10 is because 2010 is the year the paper showed up in the arXiv, but it wasn't published until 2013. Anyway, the shorthand command worked, so thank you!

Comment: BTW: There are also several `label…` fields like `labelyear` documented in section 4.2.4.2 of the `biblatex` manual.

Comment: Also look at `\DeclareLabelalphaTemplate` in the biblatex documentation - this allows complete control over the label format without resorting to new fields etc.

Comment: If you do do this make sure to apply it consistently to all preprints.

Answer (score 1):

In `alphabetic` styles, `biblatex` usually calculates the citation label from the `author` (or `editor`) field and the publication `date`/`year`.

For the shown entry your configuration will indeed produce

> IPV13

The entry key `ipv10` is almost never used to generate printed data in citations or the bibliography. It is supposed to be a purely internal ID of the entry. So if you want to force a "10" where there is no "10" in the data, you need to use something like `shorthand` to completely override the generated label. Note that you have to give the whole citation label (so you have to calculate the "IPV" part yourself) and that this `shorthand` will be used even if you use a numeric style.

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=biber,
  style=ieee-alphabetic,
  sortcites=true,
  maxbibnames   = 99, maxalphanames = 8, maxcitenames  = 6, 
  minalphanames = 6, minnames = 4,
]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{ipv10,
 AUTHOR = {Ioana, Adrian and Popa, Sorin and Vaes, Stefaan},
  TITLE = {A Class of Superrigid Group von {Neumann} Algebras},
JOURNAL = {Annals of Mathematics}, 
 VOLUME = {178},
   YEAR = {2013},
 NUMBER = {1},
  PAGES = {231-286},
shorthand = {IPV10},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem \autocite{sigfridsson,ipv10}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: [IPV10] A. Ioana, S. Popa and S. Vaes, ‘A class of superrigid group von Neumann algebras,’ Annals of Mathematics, vol. 178, no. 1, pp. 231–286, 2013.]

Alternatively, you can use set up slightly more involved machinery to override the date bit of the label with a field called `realdate` (`labeldate` would have been the obvious choice, but that field already exists with a different meaning). The advantage is that you don't use the all-overriding `shorthand` field in this case.

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\begin{filecontents}{realdate.dbx}
\DeclareDatamodelEntrytypes{realdate}

\DeclareDatamodelFields[type=field, datatype=date, skipout]{
  realdate}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[backend=biber,
  style=ieee-alphabetic,
  datamodel=realdate,
  sortcites=true,
  maxbibnames=99, maxalphanames=8, maxcitenames=6, 
  minalphanames=6, minnames=4,
]{biblatex}

\DeclareLabelalphaTemplate{
  \labelelement{
    \field[final]{shorthand}
    \field{label}
    \field[strwidth=3,strside=left,ifnames=1]{labelname}
    \field[strwidth=1,strside=left]{labelname}
  }
  \labelelement{
    \field[strwidth=2,strside=right]{realyear}
    \field[strwidth=2,strside=right]{year}
  }
}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{ipv10,
 AUTHOR = {Ioana, Adrian and Popa, Sorin and Vaes, Stefaan},
  TITLE = {A Class of Superrigid Group von {Neumann} Algebras},
JOURNAL = {Annals of Mathematics}, 
 VOLUME = {178},
   YEAR = {2013},
 NUMBER = {1},
  PAGES = {231-286},
realdate = {2010},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem \autocite{sigfridsson,ipv10}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

The disadvantage is that you have to use a `.dbx` file.